# Mean filter in fourier space

Tags: image-processing, filter, fft

I have trouble understanding how one would be able to perform a mean filtering in the Fourier space on a 2D image.

Here are my inputs :

- A mean filter of size `MxM`. `f[k1,k2] = 1/M^2`
- An image to filter of size `NxN`. `M<N`

My goal here would be to FFT both inputs, perform a Hadamard product (term by term product in the Fourier space) between both transformed frequential images in the Fourier domain.

In order to perform a Hadamard product, both frequential images should be the same size, however, this is not the case here as they will have respective sizes  `MxM` and `NxN`.
I have trouble understanding what I should do :

- Resampling the filter in the Fourier domain, so it is of size `NxN`?
- Padding the input filter with `0`'s until the desired dimensions are reached ? If so, should I center the MxM filter on the NxN grid or leave it on a corner ?

My goal in the long term would be to apply this to any filter that is too large and for which using the FFT card would be advantageous.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think my answer in the linked question answers all of your questions.

Comment: This works, thank you so much. I'd like to know if you have any explanations on why this padding technique works. Like how does adding 0s to the filter not disturb the original filter information in the Fourier domain ?

Comment: Also, I'm new here and I'm not sure what I should do with this post as your previous answer clearly answers mine. Should I delete this post or leave it here so people having the same trouble as me can be redirected to your answer on the other post ?

Comment: Leave your post up, and accept closing as duplicate. Your post will remain on the site to redirect users to the other post.

Comment: If you do a convolution in the spatial domain, padding the kernel with zeros would not affect the result (because 0 * something = 0). So padding with zeros is the correct way to ensure both image and filter have the same size. Padding in the Fourier domain has a very different effect.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In fact it makes sense now that i think of it. Adding 0s to the spatial filter does not affect its frequency information. Tell me if i'm wrong but as padding in the spatial domain results in an upsampled version of the image in the Fourier domain, then padding in the Fourier domain should actually result in an upsampled version of the spatial image, right ?

Comment: Yes, that is right.